# Swift 3 Linker issue when using a class in an extension for Objective C

Tags: xcode, linker, swift3, linker-errors

I'm trying to use Swift code into my Objective-C. Everything used to work fine until I update to Swift3, XCode 8.

With the following Swift classes:

```
@objc (TRIABC1)
public class ABC : NSObject {

}

public class DTO: NSObject {
}

extension DTO {
    @objc (TRIABC2)
    public class ABC2 : NSObject {

    }
}
```

Then in my Objective-C:

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"

- (void)abc {
    TRIABC1 *a = [[TRIABC1 alloc] init];
    TRIABC2 *b = [[TRIABC2 alloc] init];
}
```

The code in TRIABC2 will fail at the linker stage with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TRIABC2", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TRMyFile.o
```

This is obviously just a simple example. All my code is in the "extension" format. Is there a way to fix this linker problem without rewriting the entire code by removing the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, after searching a lot on this issue, it turns out to be a Swift 3 bug.

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2267